# Maintenance page Lightning community

Tags: lightning-community

How can I put my community in maintenance? I want to prevent all users from login and  showing a custom message?

Thnks

Answer (score 0):

In the administration tool, you can simply deactivate the template:
[image]

and under Sites (setup > sites) you can modify the `UnderConstructionPage` with your custom template:
[image]

You can also edit the inactive site page by editing it:
[image]

Comment: Thnks for your reply.

When I deactivate my Lightning community, appears a blank page and not UnderConstruction visualforce page

Comment: all the options can be found/edited under `sites`, I have added anotherplace to actually add the inactive site home page

Comment: I added UnderConstruction page in "Inactive Site Home Page" but not working, appears a blank page ever

Comment: that is not normal imo - there are several places for editing the under construction page, if you are not redirected accordingly, then it would probably be worth logging a case with support

Comment: Ok, I try to open a Case,
Thank you for your support